# Windows Server 2012 : Selected server has pending reboots and does not clear when rebooted

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services

Similar to the issue [here](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/kbase/VirtualizationTips/DesktopVirtualization/MicrosoftVirtualDesktopInfrastructureTips/General/SolvethependingrebooterrorinRDSdeploymentsRDMSinWindowsServer2012.html), I am blocked from Deploying what used to be called Terminal Server, and is now (confusingly) called a "Session Based Desktop Deployment" scenario within the context of the Add Roles and Features Wizard, under the top level service named "Remote Desktop Services".

I select Quick Start, and I get this far: `The server has reboots pending...`

The link in the question above shows that you should remove a registry key. I did that, and the error is still not going away, and I have rebooted seven times, and still the error is not going away. I am getting a bit frustrated. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: A comment at an msdn forum suggests that a windows update after RTM broke the ability to deploy RDS.  NICE work microsoft.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ff40dc6f-1d40-4a3c-8e48-eb8e961dcb70/server-2012-rtm-remote-desktop-connection-broker-role-wont-install

Comment: Question posted directly at microsoft site here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/625b009c-c3aa-4ba2-b9a9-6e8aae9dd6f5/windows-server-2012-reboot-pending-is-blocking-deployment-of-rds-formerly-called-terminal

Comment: Related problem and workaround:  The Grace Period Registry Key problem.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ebc032e2-ab2d-4acd-aef7-28ed548be569/how-to-set-up-remote-desktop-licensing-mode-in-windows-server-2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a while I thought the role is already installed, but that's only one of dozens of obvious checks that the RDS/TS Deployment features in WS2012 do not do properly.  If you get part way through the RDS deployment and it bails out due to an error, you will be stuck here.

My RDS role was partially installed, but not installed enough that you can confirm a role deployment from powershell, with the following command:

```
PS C:\Users\myname > get-RDLicenseConfiguration
get-RDLicenseConfiguration : A Remote Desktop Services deployment does not exist on servername.domain.local. This
operation can be performed after creating a deployment. For information about creating a deployment, run "Get-Help
Set-VDIDeployment" or "Get-Help Set-RDSHDeployment".
At line:1 char:1
+ get-RDLicenseConfiguration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-RDLicenseConfiguration
```

Here are the problems in the order that I hit them, and how I ended up thinking I was stuck where I thought I was stuck above: Trying to deploy the RDS role appears blocked on a reboot when the real problem is that the RDS role is already mostly installed, although one or more role services are not. In other words, when a feature that a normal human being wants to deploy on a computer is composed of so many little "tiny installable bits" and some are installed, and some are not, you get into a state that they did not plan for or test for. This is one of those states.

FIX PART 1:

There is a registry key that  is >0 when the system needs a reboot. It was NOT getting cleared.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ServerManager
```

Look for key named `CurrentRebootAttempts` and if >0 then change to zero.

Second half of the problem has to do with the Remote Desktop licensing system has a `Grace Period`, a way of getting you out of the box and up and running without exposing you to one of Microsoft's worst and most annoying licensing systems ever (RDS licensing), when this Grace Period ends, and licensing is properly configured, Microsoft's own tools are supposed to delete a registry key that says "Grace Period".  However, Microsoft's own people have configured that registry key so that it has permissions that not even Microsoft's tools can overcome, it cannot be deleted, in short, and you end up stuck where I'm stuck.  It looks like Licensing services were not installed, licensing modes were not configured, and licensing roles were not deployed, when in fact they were, and the real problem is that Microsoft's product (Windows Server 2012) is broken, and is lying to you.

FIX PART 2:

Deploy RDS licensing from powershell, run powershell as Administrator, and type, obviously changing `servername.domain.local` to your own FQDN:

```
import-module RemoteDesktop
New-SessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker servername.domain.local
```

When prompted, answer values shown here:

Supply values for the following parameters:
 - WebAccessServer: `servername.domain.local`
 - SessionHost[0]: `servername.domain.local`
 - SessionHost[1]:     *(press enter, but don't type anything here)*

Finally, run  `Get-RDLicenseConfiguration` and if not configured, use this command to configure licensing mode:

```
Set-RDLicenseConfiguration -LicenseServer host.domain.local  -Mode PerUser -ConnectionBroker host.domain.local
```

Answer (score 0):

One other possible cause for these messages is a Pending File Rename operation that is not clearing out.

From here: http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/kbase/VirtualizationTips/DesktopVirtualization/MicrosoftVirtualDesktopInfrastructureTips/General/SolvethependingrebooterrorinRDSdeploymentsRDMSinWindowsServer2012.html

> In that case the obvious remedy is of course to reboot the server. If that does not help, check if the key:
>
> "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\PendingFileRenameOperations"
>
> exists, if so delete it and try again. Of course it is recommended to back up the registry before doing so.

When the above solution didn't work, this ended up being the fix in my specific case.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me on server 2012 R2 preview:

[Solve the pending reboot error in RDS deployments (RDMS) in Windows Server 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20130815203844/http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/kbase/VirtualizationTips/DesktopVirtualization/MicrosoftVirtualDesktopInfrastructureTips/General/SolvethependingrebooterrorinRDSdeploymentsRDMSinWindowsServer2012.html)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Since I had this problem with Server 2012 (not R2), I'm guessing you are encountering a NEW and different issue. But this may help others googling, so I think it was okay to answer this question. Your intent is good.